# Определение адреса и редирект

Tags: javascript

Есть простой скрипт моментального редиректа:

```
<script language = 'javascript'>
 var delay = 0;
 setTimeout("document.location.href='/del/ff/add'", delay);
</script>
```

Как можно его доработать,чтобы он срабатывал если в адресе старины найдено слово "edit"?Адрес может быть разным, /del/01/edit, /edit/f2, и т.д,но нужна именно проверка,если в любом месте адреса найдено это слово "edit",то чтобы срабатывал редирект

Comment: Вот такое условии к примеру: `if (location.pathname.indexOf('edit') + 1) {`

Comment: можете дать ответ с учетом вашего комментария для этого скрипта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```html
<script language='javascript'>
  if (location.pathname.indexOf('edit') + 1) {
    var delay = 0;
    setTimeout("document.location.href='/del/ff/add'", delay);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо,работает

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если вам не нужно искать в домене или переменных или в hash это вам подойдет.